# how to automatically reload a picture using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a XML saved as pictures.xml with the text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <IMAGES>
  <PICS>
    <RELOAD>0</RELOAD>
    <LOCATION>picture1.jpg</LOCATION>
  </PICS>
  <PICS>
    <RELOAD>1</RELOAD>
    <LOCATION>picture2.jpg</LOCATION>
  </PICS>
  <PICS>
    <RELOAD>1</RELOAD>
    <LOCATION>picture3.jpg</LOCATION>
  </PICS>
</IMAGES>
```

In the server side I have a script that would change the "RELOAD" tag for `0` if I want to keep the same picture or `1` if I want to reload it.

I was thinking in using AJAX or JQuery to reload the images in the same instant as the "RELOAD" is changed to `1` in the XML file by my server side script.

My HTML is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      reloadFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "pictures.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function reloadFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var picture = 0;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PICS");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<img src=" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("LOCATION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeRELOAD + "><br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("photos").innerHTML = photos;
}
</script>


<div id="photos"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

It actually shows all pictures. I don't know what I should add in my script to make AJAX reload only the pics where in the XML file the tag RELOAD is `1`

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the condition if reload value is 1

```
function reloadFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var picture = 0;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PICS");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    if(x[i].getElementsByTagName("RELOAD")[0].node === 1) {
     table += "<img src=" +
     x[i].getElementsByTagName("LOCATION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeRELOAD + "><br>";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("photos").innerHTML = photos;
}
```